# Ionic 4 / Angular 6 - Redirect Login Page on 401/403 Using Interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors, ionic4

I'm developing an Ionic 4 with Angular 6 PWA and I'm a little stuck using the Interceptor to catch 401/403 page requests.

Here is my Interceptor code:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpUserEvent, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, empty } from "rxjs";
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

constructor(private router: Router) { }

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    if (req.headers.get('No-Auth') == "True") {
        return next.handle(req.clone());
    }

    if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null) {
        const clonedreq = req.clone({
            headers: req.headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem('userToken'))
        });

        return next.handle(clonedreq).pipe
        (
            tap(
                succ => { },
                err => {
                    if (err.status === 401 || err.status === 403){
                        localStorage.removeItem('userToken');
                        this.router.navigate(['/account/login']);
                        return empty();
                    }
                }
            )
        );
    }
    else {
        localStorage.removeItem('userToken');
        this.router.navigate(['/account/login']);
        return empty();
    }
}
}
```

So this seems to work almost as required in that it adds the token to the http request if it exists in the LocalStorage and my WepAPI verifies this on the request.

However, if I am logged in and navigate to a page I should not be allowed to (403 error) or if I am not logged in and go to a secured page (401) - the interceptor traps this fine, the localstorage item is removed and I am redirected to the login page. This again is all fine.

The problem is, the page I tried to navigate to e.g. Newsfeed that threw the 401/403 status code is now cached in the DOM. So now I am on the login page, I login fine and I redirect back to the NewsFeed page but the page is BLANK as it was not rendered with data as originally it was blocked by the 401/403 error.

How can I remove a page from the DOM cache when I have successfully logged in before redirecting.

I have tired:
this.nav.navigateRoot('/newsfeed');
but it seems to still render a blank Newsfeed page.

auth.guard.ts file

```
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router : Router, private storage: Storage){}
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot):  boolean {
      if (localStorage.getItem('userToken') != null)
      {
        return true;
      }
      this.router.navigate(['/account/login']);
      return false;
  }
}
```

Any ideas???

Thank you

Comment: For navigation purposes you should be using *guards*, the interceptor is for API requests.

Comment: I do also have Guard code in place but that just checks if the token is there or not, it does't know about 401/403 status codes coming back from the web api which is where my interceptor kicks in unless I am doing things wrong. I will edit the main question and add in the guard.ts code to demonstrate and if this is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

My bad, my AuthGuard was not firing on the correct route.

Once I had fixed that, it works as expected.

Thank you

Rowie